# Error: jQuery ... was not called -- Ajax requesting geoJSON from Node.js cross domain server

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, node.js

I'm trying to pass geoJSON data through a Node.js app running on one server to a web app running on another server. I've found a ton of other questions that deal with this, but nothing I've tried from them seem to fix my issue.

Using RestEasy extension on Chrome I'm able to use all of my RESTapi calls without problem. GET, PUT, DELETE and POST. Also pasting the url into the browser returns a page of geoJSON data with Chrome's console reporting:

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json:
```

This is the first time I've wrote something like this where I want to pull that data in to a client webapp to render geoJSON data to a map.

First I understand that a cross domain setup requires me to use JSONP, whilst I'm not familiar with that I figured first step is to receive it, then go about reworking into geojson for the map to understand. 
I installed CORS into my Node.js app which seemed to resolve my cross domain issues, but now I'm getting this jQuery error.

This is my client side ajax function:

```
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        console.log("Running AJAX");
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/jsonp; charset=utf-8",
            url: myUrl,
            cache: false,
            timeout: 5000,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            crossDomain: true,
            data: "{}",
            success: function (data)
            {
                // do my stuff
                console.log("Reading Data");
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
            {
                console.log("http Status Response: " + xhr.status);
                console.log(thrownError);
            }
        });
    });
```

This is my Node.js app on the server:

```
app.get('/api/objects', function(req, res)
{
    Object.getObjects(function(err, objects)
    {
        if (err)
        { 
            res.json(err);
        } 

        res.jsonp(objects); 
    });
});
```

Here's the error from Chrome console:

```
http Status Response: 200
Error: jQuery31108564601072970404_1485231436558 was not called
at Function.error (jquery.min.js:2)
at b.converters.script json (jquery.min.js:4)
at Nb (jquery.min.js:4)
at A (jquery.min.js:4)
at HTMLScriptElement.c (jquery.min.js:4)
at HTMLScriptElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
at HTMLScriptElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the issue.
Turns out that restarting apache (the server running the node.js app) does NOT restart the node.js application. 
So my changes on the server were never being applied.

Here's what the console now reads after restarting the node.js app. Lesson learned.

```
Reading Data
Array[16]
0: Object__v: 0_id: "58815cd0110dcc3b1e51d411"geometry: Objectproperties: Objecttype: "Feature"__proto__: 
Object1: 
Object2: 
Object3: 
Object4: 
Object5: 
Object6:
Object7: 
Object8: 
Object9: 
Object10: 
Object11: 
Object12: 
Object13: 
Object14: 
Object15: 
Object
length: 16
__proto__: Array[0]
```